# How to join names of subdirectories and files for processing - python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to loop through a directory and read the files of each subdirectory. However, I need to keep track of the name of the subdirectory as it is a time value. I managed to create a dictionary that looks as follows:

```
dict = {'time1/dir1':['file1.ext', 'file2.ext'], 'time2/dir2':['name1.ext', 'name2.ext'}
```

But I have not been able to find the correct way to pass the complete name of the file to a function.

As I am trying to use `np.fromfile()`, I need to recursively join the name of the directory/time with each of the files in the list and store them in a way such that I have:

```
dict2 = {'time1/dir1':[value1, value2], 'time2/dir2':[value1, value2], }
```

I also read the directory as a pandas DataFrame, but I still need to read the files in such a way that the time is consistent.

I have tried using and mixing `os.walk(), os.path.join(), os.listdir(), glob.glob()` and others but my logic might be wrong when using these functions.

I know there might be a more robust, simple way to loop directly and maintaining the timestamp/directory name instead of creating a great number of directories and lists.

Comment: Why `os.path.join()` did not work? Why didn't you create it `['time1/dir1/file1.ext', 'time1/dir1/file2.ext', ...]`?

Comment: what did you try so far? ```os.path.join() should work```

Comment: @abccd I have tried looping with `os.walk()`through the directories. The problem is that I need to know which directory I am using. I don't want to have a list with all the paths from the home directory as this will not allow me to separate the each file. That is why I created a dictionary but I have not found a way to make the join of the names and have them ready to plug into the `np.fromfile()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you're looking for?

```
import os
import os.path
base_path = "my/base/path"
directory_generator = os.walk(base_path)
next(directory_generator)
path_tree = {}
for root_path, directories, files in directory_generator:
    path_tree[os.path.basename(root_path)] = [
        os.path.join(root_path, file_path) for file_path in files]
```

The result is this:

```
{
    "dir1": [
        "my/full/path/dir1/file1.ext",
        "my/full/path/dir1/file2.ext"
    ],
    "dir2": [
        "my/full/path/dir2/anotherfile1.ext",
        "my/full/path/dir2/anotherfile2.ext"
    ],
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly, however, given that I have 16 directories each with 40 files it might be easier to follow these steps to create function that runs independently for individual folders and then somehow merge the results or join them at a later stage. Thank you indeed!

Comment: @ireinstein you wished for a dict ;-) `os.walk()` is a generator anyway so just do everything inside it's loop, should take no memory at all.